# WP 8.1 calculating driving route error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm writing an application for Windows Phone 8.1 which uses Maps service. I set the AppId in package.appxmanifest and the auth token in XAML map component.

App works perfectly when running on emulator or any device from Visual Studio. I published it (in hidden mode) to the Store but if I install from there it won't work.
It can search addresses and display them on map but calculating driving routes (MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync) returns typically NetworkFailure status. Earlier I experienced this error (on emulator or test device) only when I forgot to set correct Application Id in manifest but now it appeared again.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your apps manifest you are probably not requesting a permission that is needed for your app to run